# Does anyone know what brand and model is the bicycle in photo?

Tags: identify-this-bike

This photograph is from early to mid 1960. Any ideas as to what this bicycle is? This has been bothering me for decades. Can't find anything like it anywhere.[image]

Comment: It's almost certainly a department store bike -- Sears, Western Auto, etc.

Comment: (The frame appears identical to many "Western Flyer" images, but I can't find a matching "tank".)

Comment: (And apparently the same frame style was used by Sears, Schwinn, and Columbus)

Comment: I’m sure it says Schwinn on the chain guard but my eyes are not that great and if I zoom I’m it goes blurry. The guys foot being in the way doesn’t help either

Comment: Long shot, but do you still have access to the bike ?

Answer (score 8):

It's a 1961 Hawthorne Twin Bean Tank Bike sold by Montgomery Ward.

[image]
[1961 Montgomery Ward Christmas Book page 180](https://christmas.musetechnical.com/ShowCatalogPage/1961-Montgomery-Ward-Christmas-Book/0180)

Here's one in the wild
[image]
[ratrodbikes.com](https://ratrodbikes.com/forum/index.php?threads/lets-see-hawthorne-bicycles.23575/page-15)

The model was sold in 1960 and 1961. [The 1960 version](https://christmas.musetechnical.com/ShowCatalogPage/1960-Montgomery-Ward-Christmas-Book/0236) has slightly different graphics.

> The Hawthorne bikes were made by CWC (Cleveland Welding Company) the maker of the Roadmaster bicycles) since 1934, and were distributed by Montgomery Ward across the country.
> [american-vintage-bicycles.com](https://www.american-vintage-bicycles.com/home/bicycle-manufacturers/hawthorne-bicycles/)

Comment: Yep, 100% match.  Even without the paint pattern matching, that full sized tank is fairly unique.

Comment: Great find +1, did you know or was that a lot of Google

Comment: @DanK It was a lot of Google. The clue of early to mid 60s helped. I knew it was a department store bike so finding the Sears / Montgomery Ward / JC Penny catalogs online gave me a resource.

Comment: +1, Well done!!